# PHP runs the entire code and doesn't wait for input

Tags: php, post

I'm having a basic problem with PHP. I want to input many data by requesting from a form:

```
do{
        if (isset($_POST['x'])&&($_POST['y'])){
            $x = $_POST['x'];
            $y = $_POST['y'];
            //núclero de processamento
            if ($x > 0 && $y > 0){
                echo "$x    $y  primeiro quadrante";
            } elseif ($x > 0 && $y < 0){
                echo "$x    $y  segundo quadrante";
            } elseif ($x < 0 && $y < 0){
                echo "$x    $y  terceiro quadrante";
            } elseif ($x < 0 && $y > 0){
                echo "$x    $y  quarto quadrante";
            } 
        }
    } while($x && $y != 0);
```

In this case i have to use a loop, but here's the deal, i have to input indefinite coordinates on the form and whenever i enter a 0 it should break the loop and process the data printing out the results for each data. BUT it processes a single form, reloads the page and loops forever. What am i missing?

Comment: Why is there even loop needed?

Comment: Your loop does the exact same checks on the exact same values on each iteration. Not sure what else you expect that loop to do?

Comment: @GabrielFreitas Are you saying you can post multiple coordinate pairs by submitting the form once? If so, what exactly does $_POST['x'] or $_POST['y'] contain then?

Comment: @Ingus because it asks for you to enter an indefinite number of coordinates

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo i want it to storage indefinite data without sending the form, that must happen only if one of the coordinates is 0

Comment: Also, `isset($_POST['x'])&&($_POST['y'])` and the similar login in while looks odd. I'm guessing you want `isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y'])`

Comment: @GabrielFreitas I understand what you want, but my question is about the _format_ of the incoming data(in $_POST). Are $_POST['x'] and $_POST['y'] arrays if you send multiple coordinates, or what? As said above, if you don't send multiple coordinate pairs, but multiple requests with one pair each, then the loop has no purpose. Can you show the HTML for your form? I'd really recommend you install a PHP debugger, so that you can see contents of variables. Invaluable in cases like this.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo here's the exercise:
Write a code to read and indefinite number of XY coordinates.
For each coordinate write down which quadrant it belongs to
The code must stop if one of the coordinates if 0
ie:
2 3 = "first"
-1 -2 = "third"
4 -3 = "second"
...
0 2 stop

Comment: @GabrielFreitas Ok. But how have you tried to solve it? You submit the XY coordinates using a form, right? What's the HTML code for that form?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Im using Netbeans for it, how can i post a code here? It has too many characters

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo the HTML has 2 input number forms, the PHP uses POST to retrieve them. I'm trying to input them on an indefinite array as well.

Comment: @GabrielFreitas Edit it(we're talking about _one_ form, right? Not multiple?), remove the parts that aren't strictly needed to understand how your form works? And to be nitpicky, PHP doesn't "_fetch_" data from forms, the forms are _sent_ to the backend/PHP :)

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Didn't get that. What parts? I'm new to PHP. In other languages like C for example all you have to do is declare 2 variables and input them inside a loop with some kind of "read" command.

Comment: The web doesn't work like that. Your browser sends a request to the server/backend/PHP. If the particular file you request(e.g /index.php) requires some data to d oits job then you attach some data. But _you can't keep inputting new data continuously_. The data you sent initially with the request is all there is, you can't send (3,2) and (1,1) first, and then enter (0,0) later. Multiple coordinates are possible, but you must send them all at once.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo that's exactly what i was trying to do haha, thinking like any compiled language. How can i do it then?

Comment: You should go read up on some basics of HTTP first of all. You will need to send any new data that gets input, to the server in a new request. If you still need “previous” data to be able to perform whatever the server side is supposed to do - then you either need to send that data again as well, or store it on the server side the first time it gets send - for example in the user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web and HTTP doesn't work that way, you can't continuously input data, wait some time and then input some more. Instead it is like htis:

1. When you click Submit in your browser, then the browser assembles a "package" or request, and sends it to the site that the form specifies.
2. The web server software on the receiving end receives that request. Part of the request is the path for the file/code that should process the form data that your browser sent.
3. That code is now run/loaded by the web server. In case of a .php file the web server asks a PHP interpreter for help.
4. The web server passes the form data that came with your request to the PHP interpreter. Now the PHP code is run, and the output(echo, var_dump, etc..) is collected by the web server.
5. That output is then sent back to your browser from the web server.

As is hopefully shown above there is no moment of interactivity in this process. A request to a web server consists of one point in time. Otherwise you make a new/separate/different request later, to the same piece of code on the server. But the code doesn't remember anything about the last run(unless you specifically add code to save info about each request somewhere, but that's another ball game..).

The interactivity you need here would be one of

- adding JavaScript to the webpage(checking the numbers as they're entered)
- rewriting the PHP code so that it runs from the console(i.e locally, no web server/browser involved)(A loop, ask for one pair of XY and then output the quadrant)
- rewrite the code so that it supports receiving indefinite number of coordinate pairs(probably two arrays in the request, one for the X coordinates and one for the Y coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a php script is a one time shot, all the code is going to be execute, there's not stop or interaction for the user. In your case your loop never stop because you want to change the value once it was executed (this is not possible). If you want to create an interactive app on the shell with php here is the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php.

hope it helps.

Comment: I noticed that, but in that case how can it retrieve an indefinite number of data from a form (without using interactive shell)?

Comment: you can pass a value of iterations, loop X amount of times.

Answer (score 1):

Put your if statement outside the loop

```html
if (isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y'])){
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    do{ 
            
        //núclero de processamento
        if ($x > 0 && $y > 0){
            echo "$x    $y  primeiro quadrante";
        } elseif ($x > 0 && $y < 0){
            echo "$x    $y  segundo quadrante";
        } elseif ($x < 0 && $y < 0){
            echo "$x    $y  terceiro quadrante";
        } elseif ($x < 0 && $y > 0){
            echo "$x    $y  quarto quadrante";
        }  
    } while($x && $y != 0);
 }
```

Comment: No use of the loop here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this using a website, you need a form, where the user can input the values, then the user have to submit this form, when the data is inserted. Now you can check the input (eg. do your work with it or check, if 0 was inserted). Now you can display the resulting data and the form to input the next data. If you want to work with the data you just worked with when the user submits the next form, you either need to store these values on your server (e.g. in a database) or inside the website (e.g. using a hidden html field).